# ResultSet que devuelva un dato en especifico

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Oigan, esta es la pregunta mas complicada que he hecho hasta ahora y por el cual necesitaré el mayor entendimeinto posible puesto que yo tampoco sé en donde estoy deambulando, es más les compartiré parte del código.

Si saben lo que es el `ResultSet` verdad? Ese que con el `rs.getString(n)` te devuelve un cierto dato siempre y cuando utilices un `WHERE id=''` o algun otro dato en específico pues que con el simple `SELECT * FROM tabla` pues te devolverá todos los datos.

Bueno estoy en un dilema donde estoy estoy usando igual `Connection`, `PreparedStatement` o `Statement` para los que utilizan el otro objeto y ResultSet, bueno, como sabrán, para obtener un dato específico como poe ejemplo `select * from tabla where folio=?`, bueno ese folio contiene x cantidad de datos y dichos datos importantes como un domicilio, teléfono, nombre, etc.
Bueno, me encuentro con el problema de que esoty usando un `<select></select>` para que los datos de dicha columna me los rellene a un input, miren vean el código:

```
    <select id="opciona" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Ingrese el folio correspondiente')" onchange="setCustomValidity('')" required>
                        <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                        <%
                            Connection c = null;
                            PreparedStatement p = null;
                            ResultSet r = null;
                            
                            try{
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
                                p = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM acrerequi WHERE situacion='AUTORIZADO'"); 
                                r = p.executeQuery();
                                
                                while(r.next()){
                        %>
                        <option><%=r.getString(2)%></option>
                        <%
                            Connection c1 = null;
                            PreparedStatement p1 = null;
                            ResultSet r1 = null;
                            
                            try{
                                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                                c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rhcontino?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "root", "esmeraldapimentel");
                                p1 = c1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM acrerequi WHERE id='"+r.getString(2)+"'"); 
                                r1 = p1.executeQuery();
                                
                                while(r1.next()){ 
                        %>
                        <script>
                            let opcionesa  = document.getElementById("opciona")
                            let divaa = document.getElementById("diva1")
                            let divasa = document.getElementById("diva2")
                            
                            let cajaTextoP = document.getElementById("ctxp")
                            let cajaTextoZ = document.getElementById("ctxz")
          
                            opcionesa.addEventListener("change", () => {
                            let elecciona = opcionesa.options[opcionesa.selectedIndex].text
    //                            
                                if(elecciona === "<%=r.getString(2)%>") {
                                    divaa.style.display = "inline"
                                    cajaTextoP.value = "<%=r1.getString(8)%>";
                                    cajaTextoZ.value = "<%=r1.getString(9)%>";
                                }
                                else {
                                    divaa.style.display = "inline"
                                    cajaTextoP.value = "";
                                    cajaTextoZ.value = "";
                                }
                            })
                        </script>
                        <%
                            }
    }catch(Exception e){}
                        %>
                        <%
                                }
                            }catch(Exception e){}
                            %>
                    </select>
```

Estoy usando script para que me funcione relacionalmente para que me rellene los datos en las cajas de texto:

```
    <div id="diva1" style="border-color: black; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-radius: 7px; font-size: 12px">
                    
                    <br>
                    <div style="width: 45%; float: left"><label>Puesto: </label><input id="ctxp" type="text" name='puesto' style="width: 85%" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Ingrese el puesto que busca')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required/></div>
                    <div style="width: 18%; float: left"><label>Zona: </label><input id="ctxz" type="text" name='zona' style="width: 70%" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Ingrese la zona')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" required/></div> 
                </div>
```

El problema es que pretendo con el `rs.getString(n)` sacar un resultado individual, que no me salgan 2, 3 resultados al mismo tiempo porque me doy cuenta que el primer dato es el que toma en cuenta el sistema, los otros 3, 4 datos ya no los marca y por lo que he visto, tendría que echar mano de otras `Connection, PreparedStatement, ResultSet` y o sea, ¿de uno por uno sacar fijamente un dato? `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=1; SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id=2;` y asi sucesivamente ¿para sacar los datos de un dato diferente?, eso está muy tedioso.

Necesito ayuda o no sé si seguir con el `ResultSet getString` sea el camino equivocado y a lo mejor sea otro método. Les agradeceré mucho si me ayudan con este grandísimo detalle, gracias.

Comment: Te devuelvo la pregunta: Sabes lo que es el resultSet? Es el conjunto de N registros que retorna la ejecución de un Statement, junto con otra metadata asociada a la ejecución. Si ejecutas N veces una instrucción filtrando por idFolio, haces N consultas a la BD y eso es caro. Si haces UNA y recorres el resultSet UNA vez, el tiempo total seguro será menor. Ya que te dé pereza recorrer N registros, pues usas `while(resultSet.next())` y haces algo por cada registro... que es lo que ya estás haciendo. No sé con certeza qué es lo que te parece raro

Comment: yo ni siquiera encuentro una duda aca :(

Comment: Quiero seleccionar los datos de un dato, ese es el dilema, con esa codificación solo me toma en cuenta el dato número 1 de la base de datos habiendo 4 dentro de la tabla y no las toma en cuenta, no las marca. Estoy haciendo una prueba sin el Javascript, en servlet pero no estoy convencido, cuando me redirecciona no coincide el dato que elegí con los datos de ese mismo resultado cosa que con Javascript si pasaba pero repito como no está tomando en cuenta los demás resultados de la tabla, los deja en blanco, desde ahí esto valió o sea